# Google visualisation chart control - stringFilter

Tags: javascript, html, variables, google-visualization

Here I have a very powerful google table with control: http://jsbin.com/IhEmetI/1/edit

and CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Prepare the data
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Donuts eaten'],
          ['Michael' , 'Male', 12, 5],
          ['Elisa', 'Female', 20, 7],
          ['Robert', 'Male', 7, 3],
          ['John', 'Male', 54, 2],
          ['Jessica', 'Female', 22, 6],
          ['Aaron', 'Male', 3, 1],
          ['Margareth', 'Female', 42, 8],
          ['Miranda', 'Female', 33, 6]
        ]);

        // Define a slider control for the Age column.
        var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'control1',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Age',
          'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}
          }
        });


        // Define a category picker control for the Gender column
        var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'control2',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Gender',
            'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
              'allowTyping': false,
              'allowMultiple': false
            }
          }
        });
        var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'StringFilter',
          'containerId': 'control3',
          'options': {
          'filterColumnLabel': 'Name',
          'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}

          }
        });

        // Define a Pie chart
        var pie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'chart1',
          'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'legend': 'none',
            'title': 'Donuts eaten per person',
            'chartArea': {'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
            'pieSliceText': 'label'
          },
          // Instruct the piechart to use colums 0 (Name) and 3 (Donuts Eaten)
          // from the 'data' DataTable.
          'view': {'columns': [0, 3]}
        });

        // Define a table
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'Table',
          'containerId': 'chart2',
          'options': {
            'width': '300px'
          }
        });

        // Create a dashboard
        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
            // Establish bindings, declaring the both the slider and the category
            // picker will drive both charts.
            bind([slider, categoryPicker], [pie, table], [stringFilter, table]).
            // Draw the entire dashboard.
            draw(data);
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="dashboard">
      <table>
        <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
          <td style='width: 300px; font-size: 0.9em;'>
            <div id="control1"></div>
            <div id="control2"></div>
            <div id="control3"></div>
            <div id="control4"></div>

          </td>
          <td style='width: 600px'>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart3"></div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart4"></div>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

​
but I can't show stringFilter, so to search column by Name ... what is problem with this code:

```
var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'StringFilter',
          'containerId': 'control3',
          'options': {
          'filterColumnLabel': 'Name',
          'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}

          }
        });
```

and HTML:

```
    <div id="control3"></div>
```

So there is basic google visualisation table and control chart usage, and I need to filter column by name, but dont work. What is exactly problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `Dashboard#bind` is not formatted correctly.  If you want to bind the control to both the PieChart and the Table, you need to specify it like this:

```
// Create a dashboard
new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
// bind the NumberRangeFilter, CategoryFilter, and StringFilter to the PieChart and Table
bind([slider, categoryPicker, stringFilter], [pie, table]).
// Draw the entire dashboard.
draw(data);
```

If you want the StringFilter to control only the table, you need to specify it like this:

```
// Create a dashboard
new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
// bind the NumberRangeFilter and CategoryFilter to the PieChart and Table
bind([slider, categoryPicker], [pie, table]).
// bind the StringFilter to the Table
bind([stringFilter], [table]).
// Draw the entire dashboard.
draw(data);
```

**[Edit - code to properly set the** `cssClassNames` **option]**

```
var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'chart2',
    options: {
        cssClassNames: cssClassNames,
        allowHtml: true
    }
});
```

Comment: its a very very powerfull library, only is bad that dont have an CRUD function implemented, do you now any tutorial or example how to change data from table ???

Comment: Also now here I can implement css style to table: http://jsbin.com/IhEmetI/4 WHY?

Comment: You must specify the `cssClassNames` and `allowHtml` options in your Table to style it.  I'll update the answer with details.  You could try to implement CRUD operations in the Table by setting the formatted values of elements to input fields, but I think that would be a rather clunky way to do it.

Comment: can do it in this way: get data with json from database, and when I update database to call again function draw()...

Comment: Do you want to auto-refresh your data when the database changes, or do you want the ability to push changes from the web to your database?

Comment: What is better? I just want to can do CRUD functions with database php/mysql implementation

Comment: On edit I need ability to push changes from the web to database and on add new row I need ability to add to database and to show new data on table...

Comment: You need to decide what the user interface for these changes is going to be, and then you can think about how to make the Table visualization work with your user interface.

Comment: Yes, but you have to decide what the interface for that will be.  How will the user make changes to existing data?  How will the user add new data to the table?

Comment: I think that I can create an modal bootsrapt window on button click and then populate with values and send to database ...